# Emacs doesn't display color fonts at all

Tags: fonts

[image: screenshot with an example]
I tried to add `Noto Color Emoji` from Google Noto as my font for Emoji in GNU Emacs, as mentioned in [here](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_list_and_set_font.html), but for some reason GNU Emacs doesn't display these characters properly in its window. I'm using GNU Emacs 24.5.1 on GNU/Linux. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong.

Emacs for Linux uses XFT for font rendering, and XFT doesn't yet support the color fonts. See [this mailing list thread from Dec 2015](http://emacs-devel.gnu.narkive.com/O7hbDsw3/status-of-multicolor-fonts). Richard Stallman writes in that thread that it's a low priority and they don't care about color fonts. Also in that thread you can see that they disabled color fonts in Emacs for *Mac*, not for any technical reason but because color fonts are not supported in the Unix version of Emacs and they don't want the Mac version to have a feature that is not in the Unix version.

So I wouldn't expect to see this any time soon.

Comment: Actually, the feature is available in some development builds: `...* Changes in Emacs 27.1 ... ** Multicolor fonts such as "Noto Color Emoji" can be displayed on
Emacs configured with Cairo drawing and linked with cairo >= 1.16.0. ...`

Comment: That's great to hear!

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use Emacs terminal (`emacs -nw`) on a terminal emulator that support color emoji.

Edit:
Emacs can be run as GUI or terminal application. To start emacs terminal, open your terminal emulator (iTerm or iTerm2 in MacOS, Mate-Terminal or Gnaome-Terminal in Linux) and run the command `emacs -nw` in the terminal emulator. When running in terminal mode, the glyphs and fonts are not in control of Emacs and it must display what the terminal emulator is giving. With a terminal that support color emojis, you can force Emacs terminal to display them.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Color emojis work with the noto color emoji and other emoji fonts  in emacs 28

I tried to use emojis in the terminal on emacs 26 but it was glitched when I scrolled up and down. That was fixed when I upgrade as well

Now I am using GNU Emacs 28.0.50

Comment: Please specify the Emacs release or prerelease info for the build you're using. Just "2020" doesn't mean much.

Comment: MS-Windows? macOS? or GNU/Linux? Please clarify